# Can SimpleFramework deserialize skipping arbitrary depths along the way?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I'm deserializing some XML that and I'd like to be able to easily deal with slightly different versions of the format. I'm a consumer of this XML, I cannot control the format to make my job easier. One version of the XML contains elements like this:

```
<food>
  <entry name="thing1">
    <member>apple</member>
  </entry>
  <entry name="thing2">
    <member>orange</member>
  </entry>
</food>
```

I've got an annotated class like this to parse it:

```
@Root(strict=false) public static class Food {
    @Attribute public String name;
    @ElementList(entry="member", inline=true) public List<String> members;
}
```

So far so good. Today, I discovered that the producer of this XML may also give me this to represent the same information:

```
<food>
  <name>fruits</name>
  <entry name="thing1">
    <baz>
      <member>apple</member>
    </baz>
  </entry>
  <entry name="thing2">
    <baz>
      <member>orange</member>
    </baz>
  </entry>
</food>
```

That  element is now in between *entry* and *member*. If possible, I would like a single annotated Food class that could handle both formats. These feels like something SimpleFramework could handle easily, but a search through the docs didn't help me. I'm hoping someone here knows the answer.

If I have to I know I can detect this newer schema in another way and then switch to an entirely  different set of annotated classes, but the differences are small enough, I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work to add possible elements to your class setting `required = false`?

Btw. there's always a fallback solution: implement a [Converter](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html) ([Example](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters)).

Comment: Unless I misunderstand "required=false" I don't see how it can help. I want to end up with a "members" member in the Food POJO, and I want it to parse whether the <member> element is a direct child of <entry> or whether <member> is a child of <baz> which is a child of <entry>. I'll have a look at Converter